# PHP Post Form Accepting Only One Character -- PHP CodeIgniter MVC

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I was hoping for another set of eyes on my code as I cannot figure out why my post data is only accepting the first character of the input field.

Here is my view:

```
<form id="SearchTerm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("record/search/"); ?>">
    <input name="SearchTerm" type="text"> | <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

And my controller:

```
public function search($SearchTerm = 0)
{   
    // Set Session Varaible
    $CompanyId = $this->session->userdata('CompanyId');     

    $p_data = $this->input->post('SearchTerm');
    if($p_data) {
        $SearchTerm = $p_data['SearchTerm'];
    } else {
        $SearchTerm = '0';
    }

    var_dump($SearchTerm);
```

When I dump the $SearchTerm, only the first character of the input field is being caught.
Do you pro coders have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $SearchTerm = $p_data['SearchTerm']; should probably be $SearchTerm = $p_data;

Answer (score 2):

`$p_data = $this->input->post('SearchTerm');` gets you the value of `$_POST['SearchTerm']`. So calling `$SearchTerm = $p_data['SearchTerm'];` is unnecessary and probably what is causing your issue.

```
$p_data = $this->input->post('SearchTerm');
if(!$p_data) {
    $SearchTerm = '0';
}
```

But the last if statement is probably unnecessary as well since `$this->input->post('SearchTerm')` will return false if `$_POST['SearchTerm']` is empty.

Comment: I thought $p_data = $this->input->post('SearchTerm'); returns a boolean and as such, I used it to check if the form was submitted first. Am I incorrect about this?

Comment: That will return the value of that POST variable or false if it does not exist. See [the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!
Works great! Wish I had paid more attention to that documentation.